# Comparing cells of two columns in separate sheets that start with a specific letter only

Tags: vba, excel

I am seeking to create a macro function that will compare two different columns that are on separate sheets and displays the number of matches found (simply written in a cell on `Sheet2` is sufficient).

However I do not want to include all the cells within the columns when comparing, I would like only the cells that begin with the letter `O` **(capital)** to be considered.

Below is an example of the data that I am comparing

**Sheet1:**

```
7 Work Request(s).  
OMEC/2014/253   
OELC/2014/97    
OELC/2014/98    
OMEC/2014/318   
OMEC/2014/398   
OMEC/2014/468   
OMEC/2014/439

10 Work Request(s).     
OELC/2013/904   
OMEC/2013/3544  
OMEC/2014/123   
OMEC/2014/459   
OMEC/2014/516   
OMEC/2014/514   
OELC/2014/160       
OMEC/2014/542       
OMEC/2014/543       
OELC/2014/173
```

**Sheet2:**

```
6 Work Request(s).  
OMEC/2014/253   
OELC/2014/97    
OELC/2014/98    
OMEC/2014/398   
OMEC/2014/468   
OMEC/2014/440

7 Work Request(s).  
OELC/2013/904   
OMEC/2013/3544  
OMEC/2014/123   
OMEC/2014/477   
OMEC/2014/516   
OMEC/2014/515   
OELC/2014/160
```

The idea would be to compare `Sheet2` with `Sheet1` and state that (in this case) there are ***10 similarities***.

Somewhere on sheet two I would want that to display: `Number of completed requests since last week: 10`

The `7 Work Request(s).` or the like will have to be ignored when comparing even though it is present in both columns, which is why I suggested to only compare data which begins with `O` since all relevant data will begin with `O`.

If any additional information is required let me know.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you need VBA? What about adding this in Sheet1 all the way down Col B: `=if(vlookup(a1,Sheet2!a:a,1,false),1,0)`. Hide that column if you don't want anyone to see it. Now in Sheet2, where you want the count, use the formula `=sum(Sheet1!b:b)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is very simply done (no frills, overtly complicated cells, etc), the following works fine.

**Code:**

```
Sub CountSimilar()

    Dim WS0 As Worksheet, WS1 As Worksheet
    Dim R0 As Range, R1 As Range
    Dim C0 As Range, RFound As Range
    Dim NumFound As Long, StrFound As String

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set WS0 = .Sheets("Sheet1") 'Modify as necessary.
        Set WS1 = .Sheets("Sheet2") 'Modify as necessary.
    End With

    Set R0 = WS0.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) 'Modify as necessary.
    Set R1 = WS1.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) 'Modify as necessary.
    StrFound = "The following similarities were found:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    NumFound = 0

    For Each C0 In R0
        If Left(C0.Value, 1) = "O" Then
            Set RFound = R1.Find(Trim(C0.Value))
            If Not RFound Is Nothing Then
                StrFound = StrFound & C0.Value & vbNewLine
                NumFound = NumFound + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next C0

    StrFound = StrFound & vbNewLine
    StrFound = StrFound & "The total number of similarities found is " & NumFound & "."

    MsgBox StrFound

End Sub
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

### **Further Edit:**

**Code:**

```
Sub CountSimilarDeux()

    Dim WS0 As Worksheet, WS1 As Worksheet
    Dim R0 As Range, R1 As Range
    Dim C0 As Range, RFound As Range, C1 As Range
    Dim NumFound As Long, StrFound As String
    Dim NumSht2 As Long, NumDiff As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set WS0 = .Sheets("Sheet1") 'Modify as necessary.
        Set WS1 = .Sheets("Sheet2") 'Modify as necessary.
    End With

    Set R0 = WS0.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) 'Modify as necessary.
    Set R1 = WS1.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) 'Modify as necessary.
    StrFound = "The following similarities were found:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    NumFound = 0

    For Each C0 In R0
        If Left(C0.Value, 1) = "O" Then
            Set RFound = R1.Find(Trim(C0.Value))
            If Not RFound Is Nothing Then
                StrFound = StrFound & C0.Value & vbNewLine
                NumFound = NumFound + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next C0

    NumSht2 = 0
    For Each C1 In R1
        If Left(C1.Value, 1) = "O" Then
            NumSht2 = NumSht2 + 1
        End If
    Next C1

    NumDiff = NumSht2 - NumFound

    StrFound = StrFound & vbNewLine
    StrFound = StrFound & "The total number of similarities found is " & NumFound & "." & vbNewLine
    StrFound = StrFound & "The total number of qualified strings in Sheet2 is " & NumSht2 & "." & vbNewLine
    StrFound = StrFound & "The difference is " & NumDiff & "."

    MsgBox StrFound

End Sub
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: Yes thank you this is great! ive made some minor changes but ive kept the bulk of the code.

Comment: Would it be possible to add a count for the column on sheet2. I would need to count only the cells beginning with "O" once again. Then have the MsgBox read out the difference between the total count and the similarities. 
An example would that there are 50 cells in the selected column of sheet2 that begin with "O" and there are 10 similarities that begin with the "O" when comparing both columns on separate sheets and thus the difference would be 40.